# storing multiple selections from html form in PHP array (I'm using Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I've got an HTML form which allows a user to select multiple options in a  dropdown. I then pass that data on as post data to a PHP backend (I'm using codeigniter for the backend, and the data is being passed to a model).

In javascript, I can log the value being passed, and if there are multiple values, it shows as a proper, comma separated string of values. But if log the value in PHP, it only lists the last of the multiple values. How do I get it to retain all selections? This is my code:

FORM:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/index.php/control_form/add_all" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="sel_dep">Member Dependencies</label> 
<select id="sel_dep" name="sel_dep" multiple> 
    <option value=""></option> 
    <option value="4">Soundgarden</option>
    <option value="5">Rage Against the Machine</option>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />       
</select> 
</form>
```

PHP Codeigniter Model:

```
function edit_member(){
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $v_memberdep = $this->input->post('sel_dep');
    log_message('debug', 'DEP: ' . $this->input->post('sel_dep'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the name of your select box to `f_memberdep[]` the `[]` will tell PHP that it should be passed as an array so you will receive all values.

Also should point out that your logging a field called `sel_dep` when your select box is called `f_memberdep` but that's probably just a formatting thing.

Comment: Just a note that in order to actually pass that data on to a DB field, you have to either create a completely separate table for that data to go into, or you need to serialize the data so it can go into a single field (which is what I did. Thanks fire